# JQuery, draggable and droppable, what am I missing?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I want to be able to drag events to empty divs here.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yc9WY/6/

If you drag an event to an empty div, you'll see that it does not eliminate the first one, and I can no longer drag the newly appended href to a new div.

What am I missing?

Comment: I see you are checking the dropped div to make sure there isn't an event already.  If there isn't one you are appending another draggable, which creates a duplicate.  Is this the intent and you want to be able to drag the original event again?

Comment: I changed the if check a little and it is moving the dive to the new div and is draggable again.  I have a problem with the position after.  I will look further and let you know.  http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/tYrM2/

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle now so it moves the event to the correct div and corrects the css now.  I also add a revert, so if you drop an event on a div that already has an event it moves it back to the original div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new anchor and cloning the data inside the dragged element, why don't you just *move* the element itself?

```
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
```

You'll also need to reset the position to remove the left/top properties that draggable adds (there's probably a function/option for this, but you can look around the docs).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yc9WY/27/

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is exactly what I was missing.